Unity 2D tiles turn pink upon project load or after stopping the game, after reimporting?
I've been having a bit of a problem with tiles. Here is a tileset I made:

But as I add them to the game, I noticed some things don't look quite like I want, but although I could recreate my tileset and repaint my tiles in the scene, I'd prefer if I could just update the tileset with changes that would reflect on the already placed tiles to avoid repeating work, so I've been following this process:

Use a copy of the file for this tileset and edit it in Photoshop
Once edited, find the imported tileset in the project and paste it in Windows Explorer. When asked to replace, I replace it
In Unity, reimport the tileset
In the Sprite Editor tab, slice by cell size using the same size as before, then use Smart method if I added any new tiles, then apply
In the Tile Palette tab where I have the palette for this image, drag and drop the tile palette in the exact same squares as it currently is
Overwrite in the same folder where the tile images for the palette are

When done, I see that the images drawn prior to this remain fine,

But if I play the game and stop, or close the Unity window and reopen, the tiles become pink:

I know there is an issue with importing, but where? Where is my process to update/add new tiles without losing the existing ones wrong? Please let me know if any of you know of this issue

Lol never mind. It's possible the tutorial I followed to learn this intended for new tiles only to be added and thus used the Overwrite function to update, but what I needed for this case was to Reuse as I drag the image into the tile palette
